# Keycloak 19 docker can't find suitable driver for sqlserver

Tags: sql-server, keycloak

I deployed keycloak 19 in azure app service using the quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:19.0.1 image; It's working fine when using the dev file database; but I'm having trouble when I tried to connect on my SQL server database, I followed the instruction [here](https://www.keycloak.org/server/db) but I'm getting the error below

> ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://MySDBServer:1433;databaseName=MyDatabaseName

Here's my Setup in app settings configurations

KC_DB:mssql

KC_DB_URL_HOST:[MyDatabaseServer]

KC_DB_PASSWORD:[MyDatabasePassword]

KC_DB_USERNAME:[MyDatatabaseUsername]

KC_DB_URL_DATABASE:[MydatabaseName]

KC_PROXY:edge

Comment: The linked instructions are for building a Keycloak instance that talks to PostgreSQL. Did you remember to modify `bin/kc.[sh|bat] build --db postgres` and the other commands to use Microsoft SQL Server instead?

Answer (score 0):

Passing the `--optimized` parameter to the start should fix it.

```
bin/kc.[sh|bat] start --optimized
```

In case of a Dockerfile, your ENTRYPOINT will look like:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh", "start", "--optimized"]
```

You can read about the `--optimized` parameter at the links given below.

[Optimize the Keycloak startup](https://www.keycloak.org/server/configuration#_optimize_the_keycloak_startup)

[Changes to the server configuration and startup](https://www.keycloak.org/2022/07/keycloak-1900-released#_changes_to_the_server_configuration_and_startup)